# jsFiddle working, website JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tried lots of different things, but can't seem to get this working in the live site.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.upme-field-value').filter(function(){
       $this = $(this);

       if ($this.text() === "Verified") {
           $this.html('<div id="verifiedText">Verified</div><img alt="Passed" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/verified1.png"/>');

           $this.find('#verifiedText').hide();
 }
   });
 </script>
```

here is it working in fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/4MLX3/11/

I've disabled js minify
I've uploaded the js source file to the website
I've put the script first in the header 
I've checked for errors using Chrome Developer tools, but nothing seems to work

Comment: `$(document).ready(function()`?

Comment: Open your console (F12) and notice all the lines that are red, those are errors!

Comment: You are trying to manipulate DOM stuff on your page that doesn't exist yet - a small detail that jsFiddle prevents automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jsFiddle, by default the script runs under a `window.onload` handler(2nd dropdown in the left panel).

Add your code in a dom ready handler

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.upme-field-value').filter(function () {
        $this = $(this);

        if ($this.text() === "Verified") {
            $this.html('<div id="verifiedText">Verified</div><img alt="Passed" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/verified1.png"/>');

            $this.find('#verifiedText').hide();
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Jquery ready handler missing in your script section.

```
   $(function(){
    $('.upme-field-value').filter(function(){
      $this = $(this);
       if ($this.text() === "Verified") {

          $this.html('<div id="verifiedText">Verified</div><img alt="Passed" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/verified1.png"/>');

          $this.find('#verifiedText').hide();
       }
     });
 });
```